# Linux Time persist through reboot issue

Tags: time, clock, real-time

I have a custom board that houses a  System on module(SOM) running linux kernel 4.4.15
The board has an RTC that is backed up via small battery.

I have the board running with no network connection at the moment.

I have two different SOM's. If I insert SOM A, and boot the device

`$date returns date in Feb 2020`

`$hwclock returns same date/time in Feb 2020`

If i update the system time, and RTC, and then pull the power and reboot, both commands come back up with the same date(Feb 2020).

If I insert SOM B, and boot the device, the results are the same, except that date returned on bootup is a May 2020 date/time (yesterday actually)

It seems as if there is an issue reading the time back out of the RTC on boot, and then the system pulls a saved date/time from somwhere, but where could that be?

I even removed the hwclock.sh script in /etc/init.d (which is linked into all the rc.X folders)

I also moved the hwclock binary from /sbin/ to somewhere else to stop any other callers from setting the rtc, but when I run it manually after booting, it still seems to have the incorrect date/time (either feb 2020, or yesterday)
This also seems strange since without the hwclock binary in its normal place, how are the system clock and hwclock reporting the same time after a power cycle?

Is there some other service/place where time would be written to a file and used to set system time on boot?

Edit:

set system and rtc time

```
$ cat /proc/driver/rtc
rtc_time    : 00:00:16
rtc_date    : 2020-05-15
alrm_time    : 00:00:00
alrm_date    : 1970-01-01
alarm_IRQ    : no
alrm_pending    : no
update IRQ enabled    : no
periodic IRQ enabled    : no
periodic IRQ frequency    : 1
max user IRQ frequency    : 64
24hr        : yes
```

full power cycle, and rtc has reverted.

```
$cat /proc/driver/rtc
rtc_time    : 14:54:22
rtc_date    : 2020-05-14
alrm_time    : 00:00:00
alrm_date    : 1970-01-01
alarm_IRQ    : no
alrm_pending    : no
update IRQ enabled    : no
periodic IRQ enabled    : no
periodic IRQ frequency    : 1
max user IRQ frequency    : 64
24hr        : yes
```

Edit2:

All the testing when I have when I power cycled it, was to actually pull the power cord, wait a few seconds and plug it back in. (This is an embeded linux device, so this is not uncommon) However, I set the time to today, and then issued reboot command, (power was not removed) it came back up with the same time I set (midnight)   Then when a power cycle was done the next time, it came back up with that same date (today),

So something in the reboot process forces the OS to save its time somewhere I think. and then on startup it is setting the rtc with that rather then reading from it.

Comment: Is the "small battery" charged (how many volts does it have)? In both cards.

Comment: @Isaac, there is only one board(which contains the rtc chip, and battery) I change out the SOM and get those results. so they are both using the same rtc/battery. Charge does seem a little low (3.2V) but again, two different SOM's get two different dates on boot with the same RTC

Comment: If the battery is CR2032 (the usual Alkaline battery in such cases), 3.2 volts is perfectly fine. Then the problem is not with the battery.

Comment: Its actually not a battery, its a capacitor. I guess I was expecting it to be at 3.3, I even tried discharging it and booting up, get the same result.

Comment: Depending on the platform `cat /proc/driver/rtc` can give you some info on the rtc, including battery ok.

Comment: @meuh added the contents of /proc/driver/rtc before and after reboot

Comment: Also, an offical reboot changes what persists, more info in the main question.

Comment: Being a "custom board" there is no way we can divine the answer. Could you give the name, model and serial number of the board ?

Comment: Perhaps your system has been configured with something like [fake-hwclock](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/fake-hwclock.8.html) which saves time in a file, provided you reboot cleanly.

Comment: Yep, thats the case @meuh, there was a file being produced during a shutdown that was then loaded on the next boot.